# Unity2D Detecting multiple trigger collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an attack system to my game and for the moment is something like this:

```
 private void Start()
{
    triggerActive = false;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (triggerActive)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            enemyOne.Attacked();
        }
    }
}

private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
{

    triggerActive = true;
   enemyOne = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Hittable>();
   
}
private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    triggerActive = false;
    enemyOne = null;
    
}
```

For the moment this works good, but now I want to try to detect more than one collider at the same so I can attack two different enemies at the same time. How could I do that?

Comment: For damage-over-time, you'd probably want to use the ```OnTriggerStay```. But for hit-once attacks you really only need ```OnTriggerEnter``` as Shingo explains below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll to detect all the colliders (enemies) in a certain radius.
Or you can also use Physics2D.CircleCastAll to detect all the colliders (enemies) except those are hidden by other ones.

For more information, you should check the Unity Documentation.

Comment: Does it work with physics2D.OverlapArea? I tried to use it to store all the enemies hitten in an array but I couldn't make it work as I don't undertand too much how to use it.

Comment: You can check out my channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCWe_os3p4z3DBnQ4B5DUTfw/videos

Answer (score 0):

You could check in OnTriggerStay2D:

```
if (col.gameobject == enemyone)
...
else if (col.gameobject == enemytwo)
...
```

For enemyone and enemytwo you could use two public gameobjects that you reference
externally in the Unity editor.

There are other examples how you can iterate over many enemies:

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collision collision)
{
        foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
        {
            print(contact.thisCollider.name + " hit " + contact.otherCollider.name);
            // Visualize the contact point
            Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is going to be a good solution since there is going to be a lot of enemies.

Answer (score 0):

First you need move the trigger flag from this class to the Hittable class.

```
class Hittable
{
    public bool isHit = false;
}
```

Then you need to replace enemyOne with a list of Hittable objects.

```
List<Hittable> enemies = new List<Hittable>();
```

When the trigger hits the enemy, we add the enemy into the enemy list. OnTriggerExit2D is not necessary, because we clear the list every frame.

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
{
   var enemy = col.gameObject.GetComponent<Hittable>();
   if (!enemy.isHit)
   {
       enemy.isHit = true;
       enemies.Add(enemy);
   }
}
```

Finally we attack the enemies in the list every frame.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (enemies.Count > 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            foreach (var enemy in enemies)
            {
                enemy.isHit = false;
                enemy.Attacked();
            }
        }
        enemies.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: I read the OP as looking for how to do AOE, not DOT.  Still true on needing a list.
Not sure why you're registering the hit in OnTriggerStay but not proc'ing the damage until Update...  Why not proc the damage inside the Trigger event?  Using the Hittable is fine, but could just as easily track a unique Set.

Comment: @Immersive Because the OP processes the damage inside the Update method.

Comment: Ahh. Fair enough. =)